# ValueError while iterating and updating a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with identical column names and need to iterate through both of them simultaneously to see if there are any overlaps and if there is a date overlap and if yes,  update one of the column of the data frame,  which is associated with the inner loop.

I am currently able to determine if there is overlap,  but not able to update the value  and getting ValueError.

## apr19_copy

```
cmdb    type            begin                end             duration   
xyz Planned Outage  2019-03-31 09:45:00 2019-03-31 11:27:00   12291 
xyz Planned Outage  2019-04-20 07:25:00 2019-04-22 10:50:00  185100
```

## apr19

```
cmdb type           begin             end           duration    
xyz Outage  2019-04-30 15:20:00 2019-05-01 00:17:00   32279 
xyz Outage  2019-04-20 21:42:00 2019-04-20 21:43:00      60
```

I have tried using itertuples,  iterrows etc to no avail.

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import namedtuple
Range = namedtuple('Range', ['begin', 'end'])

for item in apr19_copy.itertuples():
    r1 = Range(begin = item.begin, end = item.end)
    for item_outage in apr19.itertuples():
        r2 = Range(begin = item_outage.begin,  end = item_outage.end)
        latest_start = max(r1.begin,  r2.begin)
        earliest_end = min(r1.end,  r2.end)
        if(latest_start > earliest_end):
            continue
        diff = (earliest_end - latest_start).seconds + 1
        overlap = max(0, diff)
        print(item_outage.duration)
        apr19.set_value(item_outage.index, 'duration',  item_outage.duration 
                                                        - overlap)
```

After running the above code piece I would expect duration in the second row  of apr19 dataframe to be set to 0.  The resulting dataframe should be as below  (Please note * around the expected value)

## apr19

```
cmdb type           begin             end           duration    
xyz Outage  2019-04-30 15:20:00 2019-05-01 00:17:00   32279 
xyz Outage  2019-04-20 21:42:00 2019-04-20 21:43:00      *0*
```

I however get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please post what you expect your final dataframe to look like. it is not clear what you are trying to update. This can be much simpler than you are making it, and I think I can provide a solution but I'd just like it to match what you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks kennetz.  I have updated the question with what I expect in the resulting dataframe

Comment: this code won't run, particularly the `Range()` instructions

Comment: Yes Yuca.  Oversight from myside.  Added few imports and it should work now. apologies.

Comment: cab you explain the logic behind the 0 value?

Comment: Sure.  The Apr19 DF's second row (begin and end ) is part of Apr19_copy's second row.  To avoid double counting,  the overlapping portion is subtracted from the duration.  In this case the entire duration is overlapping and hence it should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by `item_outage.index`. It is obtained from `itertuples` and `index` represents a method on it. To get the index of the row, you must use `Index`. So you should use:

```
    apr19.set_value(item_outage.Index, 'duration',  item_outage.duration 
                                                    - overlap)
```

But my pandas versions gave me a deprecation warning for using `set_value`, so IMHO this should be better (if accepted by your pandas version):

```
    apr19.at[item_outage.Index, 'duration'] = item_outage.duration - overlap
```

It works but the value is not the expected 0 but -1 ...

Comment: hey man, no need to apologize! it's just wild to think that somewhere in the world a person thinks exactly the same thing as you at "exactly" the same time :)

Comment: OMG,  what a silly mistake from my side.  Thanks guys.  truly appreciate.  struggled with it for like 2 hours or so.  Thanks again.  Works like a charm and -1 is perfectly fine.  I had to do something else on the value and did not want to complicate.